# Find direction of the shadow given latitude / longitude, date and time

Tags: algorithm, math, wolfram-mathematica

Is there any algorithm that gives the compass direction of a shadow given latitude, longitude, date and time?

(Assuming we are an flat ground and that whatever the shadow falls from stands upright.)

Comment: If you are really looking at how to do this in Mathematica, you might be interested to know that there is a [StackExchange site specific to Mathematica](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) now.

Comment: i asked it in the StackExchange site specific to Mathematica

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for the *declination and right ascension* of the sun at a given time and location.  Hit Google.

You tagged this question 'mathematica' so look at `AstronomicalData["Sun", ...]`